# R get the particular hour from the time

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
Num    Date        Time
1      2015.05.21  12:12:12
2      2015.05.22  13:12:12  
3      2015.05.23  14:12:12
4      2015.05.24  15:12:12
5      2015.05.25  16:12:12
```

By using `weekdays(as.Date(data$Date, format='%Y.%m.%d'))` I can get the corresponding days of the week. Also by using `months` I can get the corresponding months. Is there a way to get the hour only in a new column? Something like `hours(as.Date(data$Time, format='%H:%M:%S'))` which will provide me the following output.

```
Num    Date        Time      Hour
1      2015.05.21  12:12:12  12
2      2015.05.22  13:12:12  13  
3      2015.05.23  14:12:12  14
4      2015.05.24  15:12:12  15
5      2015.05.25  16:12:12  16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R doesn't have a native data type for just time values without dates.  With the sample data

```
dd<-read.table(text="Num    Date        Time
1      2015.05.21  12:12:12
2      2015.05.22  13:12:12  
3      2015.05.23  14:12:12
4      2015.05.24  15:12:12
5      2015.05.25  16:12:12", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

You can do

```
transform(dd, Hour=as.POSIXlt(paste(Date, Time), format="%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S")$hour)
```

to get

```
  Num       Date     Time Hour
1   1 2015.05.21 12:12:12   12
2   2 2015.05.22 13:12:12   13
3   3 2015.05.23 14:12:12   14
4   4 2015.05.24 15:12:12   15
5   5 2015.05.25 16:12:12   16
```

Comment: No need for adding the `Date` as well if just extracting the hour - `as.POSIXlt(dd$Time,format="%H:%M:%S")$hour` or `as.numeric(format(as.POSIXct(dd$Time,format="%H:%M:%S"),"%H"))`